# Assigning VF page to Record type by rerender tag

Tags: apex, visualforce, record-type, rendered

I have a record type for opportunity to which i need to assign this VF page. I am getting **an error** :

> Element type "apex:pageBlock" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

VF page

```
    <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateOppExtension"  >
      <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save" rendered="{if(opportunity.RecordTypeid =="012b0000000M8s5"),true,false}">
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>     
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller:

public class CreateOppExtension 
{

```
Opportunity opp {get;set;} 

String Owner {get;set;}

  ApexPages.StandardController GstdController;


 public PageReference save(){
    insert opp;            


    return new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);

}
```

Comment: By the way, "==" returns a Boolean already. You don't need the if statement. `rendered="{!opportunity.RecordTypeid =='012b0000000M8s5'}"`

Comment: Also never hardcode a recordtypeid, it will stop working when you move it to higher sandboxes as  the id will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using the code as below:

`<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save" rendered="{!if(opportunity.RecordTypeid =='012b0000000M8s5',true,false)}">`

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save" 
    rendered="{if(opportunity.RecordTypeid =="012b0000000M8s5"),true,false}">
```

With:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save" 
    rendered="{!IF(opportunity.RecordTypeid =='012b0000000M8s5', true, false)}">
```

**Details**:

There were following issues for which compiler complains about:

1. You missed an exclamation sign which is required for merge field.
2. Use single quotes for wrapping the recordtypes in condition.
3. true/false statement should be inside the parenthesis of an IF conditon.

   - Better would be get rid of IF condition, the comparison itself returns a Boolean.

     ```
     rendered="{!opportunity.RecordTypeid =='012b0000000M8s5'}"
     ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the renderd attribute as your attribute is not bind like this :-

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save" rendered="{!if(opportunity.RecordTypeid =="012b0000000M8s5"),true,false}">
```

Comment: @Reshma..I am getting same error

Comment: @DiljaanShaik did you try my method?